# How to catch 'focus out' from listitem of listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview, focus, listitem

I'm implementing a listview which will save a listitem when focus is out of that listitem. How can I achieve this? I tried to use onFocusChangeListener but it doesn't work. Anyone has an idea? Below is my code in my ListAdapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
    Spinner elem1 = (Spinner)rowView.findViewById(R.id.elem1);
    Spinner elem2 = (Spinner)rowView.findViewById(R.id.elem2);
    TextView elem3 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.elem3);

    rowView.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

    return rowView;
}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(!hasFocus) {
        // todo : save current list item.
        Logger.debug(TAG, ">>> Focus out");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use another flag, say `boolean focused;`

then:

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus) {
        focused = true;
    }
    if(!hasFocus) {
        if (focused == true) {
            // todo : save current list item.
            Logger.debug(TAG, ">>> Focus out");
            focused = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that event doesn't even get triggered.